# XSLT Loop XML element and frame a single text

Tags: xml, xslt

i have an input in below format.I want to loop with the Error element in the MessageBody and frame the response message as a single text as shown below.Can you please help me with it.

```
Input:

<Response>
<Header>
</Header>
<Messagebody>
<Error>
<ErrorCode>E</ErrorCode>
<ErrorId>100000</ErrorId>
<ErrorDescription>UserId Not Found</ErrorDescription>
</Error>
<Error>
<ErrorCode>M</ErrorCode>
<ErrorId>100001</ErrorId>
<ErrorDescription>Source System Not Found</ErrorDescription>
</Error>
</Messagebody>
</Response>

Expected Output:

<Response>
<Fault>
<Text>[E];100000;UserId Not Found,[M];100001;Source System Not Found</Text>
</Fault>
</Response>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: Hi Michael, Iam new to XSLT can you please tell me how can i acheive i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a complete solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output  method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
        <Response>
          <Fault>
            <Text><xsl:apply-templates/></Text>
          </Fault>
        </Response>  
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Error[position() > 1]">
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Error/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(';', 1, position() > 1)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring('[', 1, name()='ErrorCode')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(']', 1, name()='ErrorCode')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Response>
    <Header></Header>
    <Messagebody>
        <Error>
            <ErrorCode>E</ErrorCode>
            <ErrorId>100000</ErrorId>
            <ErrorDescription>UserId Not Found</ErrorDescription>
        </Error>
        <Error>
            <ErrorCode>M</ErrorCode>
            <ErrorId>100001</ErrorId>
            <ErrorDescription>Source System Not Found</ErrorDescription>
        </Error>
    </Messagebody>
</Response>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
[E];100000;UserId Not Found,[M];100001;Source System Not Found
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dimitre.This is what i needed,i will have a look at training courses.